# Regex tags eliminate

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex which will eliminate a particular tag but keep its value.

```
String s = "I am trying to eliminate tag link <link class < =abc>okay</link>"
```

or:

```
String s = "I am trying to eliminate tag link <link>okay</link>"
```

It is straightforward to replace the closing tag with `regex = "</link>"`, but the start tag can contain any number of attributes.

The required output should be `"I am trying to eliminate tag link okay"`

I tried `s = s.replaceAll("<link.*>$","")`, but it replaces all the text after `<link`

Comment: Please paste the text instead of a screenshot. Use code formatting (highlight the text and click the `{}` button).

Answer (score 1):

As a first approximation, `<link[^>]*>` should work. (It means to match `<link` followed by any number of characters that aren't `>`, followed by `>`.) But this approach will fail when a right angle bracket appears in an attribute value.

A much better approach is to not use regular expressions at all, but instead use an XML parser.

Comment: I tried using s.replaceAll("<link[^>]*>", ""); It keeps the link tag itnack and also if there are attributes it does not replace that: <link class = b> abc </link> output should be abc. <link> abc <link> output should be abc there can be any no of attributes in the link tag , i just want the value

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying the regular expression I gave should match a starting `link` tag. If you're looking to also match the closing tag, try `</?link[^>]*>`. If that's not what you're trying to do, please edit your question to give the exact code you're trying and an example that's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<\/?link.*?>
```

See the example here: https://regex101.com/r/yUVFpR/1

For the `replaceAll` function, try this:

```
s = s.replaceAll("<link>([^<]*)</link>","$1");
```

Comment: I tried using s.replaceAll("<//*link.*?>", ""); It keeps the link tag itnack and also if there are attributes it does not replace that: <link class = b> abc </link> output should be abc. <link> abc <link> output should be abc there can be any no of attributes in the link tag , i just want the value

Comment: I think `/?` is better than `/*` here. (No need to match more than one slash.)

Comment: @user3458716 I updated my code and added another code for the `replaceAll` function, try it out, and let me know if it works for you.